# use variable in UI of R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created quite a large app that I now want to extent by introducing tabs.  So far I have, as an example:

```
ui.R
shinyUI(
#OLD CODE
)

server.R
(
#OLD CODE
)
```

What I would like to do:

```
ui.R
shinyUI(
tabsetPanel(
"Tabs",
tabPanel("Old Code",value="tb1"),
tabPanel("New Code",value="tb2"),
id = "nlp"
),

if (id=="tb1") {
#OLD CODE
} else if (id=="tb2") {
#New Code 
} else {
#Do nothing
}
```

How do I get the if function to recognise id as a variable?
When I run the script it comes up with the error object 'id' not found.  So then I've tried input$id and output$id with no avail.

I have also tried going to the server.R and tried

```
Server.R
output$id <- renderText("id")
```

also didn't work when trying to bring that back into the UI

and I have also tried

```
Server.R
output$id <- reactive({input$id})
```

this also didn't work when I tried to use it in the UI.  Where am I going wrong and how can I use the Id variable in the UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Shiny Tabsets](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html) example, you should be putting the UI elements into each call to `tabPanel`, like so:

```
shinyUI(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
            title = "Old Code",
            plotOutput('plot1'),
            plotOutput('plot2')
            ),
        tabPanel(
            title = "New Code",
            tableOutput('table')
            ),
        id = "nlp"
        )
    )
```

Unless you are trying to do more than necessary, your code does not need to know what tab the client has selected. I may be wrong (please do not think I'm an authority on shiny), I think the elements within the not-selected tabs are not unnecessarily recalculated (unless dependencies exist and require it).

Comment: worked like a charm.  But for future reference is there actually a way to use a variable like ID made in the UI?

Comment: I don't know of a way, might be a good question for the [Google group forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/shiny-discuss).